# get y root of x in php for example 3 root of 8 is 2

Tags: php, math

i want to get x root of y. just as 3 root of 8 is 2
is there any function in php to get this result.

**sqrt** function is getting square root of the given value.
but i want n root of given value. is there another way to find it.

Comment: There should be `pow` function. Root to power n is equivalent to power to 1/n.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use something like this

> pow(8,1/3);

remember that rule ? :-)

Answer (score 3):

> x = b<sup>e</sup>

becomes:

> ln x = e ln b
>   ln x / e = ln b
>   ln b = ln x / e
>   b = *e*<sup>ln x / e</sup>

hence:

```
$b = exp(log($x) / $e);
```

Note that this will only give you one real root, if any exist. You'll need to perform math in the complex domain if you want *all* e roots.

Comment: but *log* is differ than *ln*

Answer (score 2):

To get any root of a number your can use the `pow()` function:

pow(8, 1/3)

which gives you the third root of eight.

For reference check

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php